# Postgres - remove duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have write a query to remove duplicate records from a table.

```
DELETE e FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY emp_id) AS rn
    FROM employee1
) e 
WHERE e.rn > 1
```

But i got this error

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "e"
LINE 1: DELETE e FROM.

Can someone help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique id, then use that.  But, if you don't, you can use `ctid`:

```
delete from employee1 e
    where e.ctid > (select min(e.ctid) from employee1 e2 where e2.emp_id = e.emp_id);
```

Comment: No. I don't have unique id so that i can't use MIN.

My sample data emp_id is = E1, E2, E3, E4, E2, E1, E2, E5. 

I just need to view emp_id = E1, E2, E3, E4, E5.